# Why is my assembly subroutine being called even though I'm not calling it in _start in my bootloader

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm currently developing a bios bootloader and im newer to assembly ive been reading up on it and I understand how it works but theres some things I dont understand involving the sequence of execution of my assembly code.

So basically how is my subroutine _print being called even though im not calling it.
Second how is it allocating the bios magic number if thats all the way at the end of the file even though im not reaching.

I would appreciate any help, Thanks.

```
[ORG 0000:7C00]

global _start 

_print:
    mov ah, 0x0e 
    mov al, '['
    int 0x10
    mov al, '+'
    int 0x10
    mov al, '['
    int 0x10
    ret

_start:
    jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: *Second how is it allocating the bios magic number if thats all the way at the end of the file even though im not reaching.* - The `dw` obviously is at the end of your source file, and the `times` line right before it pads out to 510 bytes.

Comment: yes but since im doing a infinite loop before that with jmp $ how is it even being called

Comment: It *isn't* ever executed at run-time by the CPU.  And at assemble-time, NASM just assembles bytes into the output file one line at a time.  It doesn't interpret your program so it doesn't take branches, just like how a C compiler is able to compile a program that contains an infinite loop like `if (foo) while(42) {} else puts("hello");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike executables run by an operating system, the boot sector doesn't have a way to designate an arbitrary entry point; it always starts at the first instruction.  So the `_start` label doesn't work as a way to specify where to start.  You have to literally put that code first.

Comment: Ok and also how is my final instruction getting called even though im using jmp $

Comment: What do you mean by "final instruction getting called"?  Note that when code starts at `_print`, the `ret` will jump to whatever random address happens to be at the random address where SS:SP points, so it's hard to predict what will happen after that.  But there's no reason to expect that your `jmp $` ever gets reached.

Comment: Ah i see that makes sense thats why i earlier when i was playing around with it i was getting unpredictabe behavior.  You see how i have dw 0xAA55 how is that instruction being called if its at the end of the file since jmp $ is a infinite loop. And how could my I add sub routines to my assembly code that arent called automatically

Comment: The entry point address of an ELF executable file can be shown by, for example, `readelf ‑‑file‑header a.out`. The mere existence an entry point field in the file header should tell you that a flat binary like code in the MBR cannot have arbitrary entry points.

Comment: @lizardcoder: `dw 0xAA55` isn't an instruction and it never gets executed, nor is it supposed to.  It's just bytes.  When the BIOS loads the first sector of the disk, it checks the last word is equal to `0xAA55`, and aborts the boot process if it isn't.  This is just in case the disk isn't meant to be bootable, in which case the first sector would contain miscellaneous data that should not be executed.

Comment: @lizardcoder; If you want to have subroutines, just put their code after the end of your "main routine" boot code.

Comment: Ok thanks guys you cleared it u p for me I appreciate it