# Where to put assembly subroutines in boot sector file

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, subroutine

I have the following boot sector written in nasm:

```
[org 0x7c00]

my_print_function:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10
    ret

_start:
    mov al, 'A'
    call my_print_function
    call my_print_function

_boot:
    jmp $
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xaa55
```

I compile with `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin` and then run `qemu boot.bin`, and I only see one character being printed, and it's the garbage character `'U'`, not `'A'`. If I change the order of `my_print_function` and `_start`, it works as intended, but the subroutine also runs one time on its own without me calling it, so it prints `'A'` three times.

Normally If i was writing assembly, I would just define the `my_print_function` before my `section .text`, and put a `global _start` in my `section .text`, but it doesn't seem like that does anything here. How can I define and use a subroutine like this without it being ran an extra time just because I define it?

Comment: The BIOS loading the boot sector has no idea about your `_start`. It will transfer control to the physical address `0x7c00`. So you should put your main there. You can put your functions after it.

Comment: Yep I realised this, but thanks for your comment!

Comment: The alternative would be to put a `jmp _start` at the beginning (at address `0x7C00`) and have the main code anywhere you like. This is necessary for some cases (when there's a "BIOS parameter block"  in the way - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block )

Comment: @Brendan that's a clever way of doing it too! Thanks, will add it to my arsenal

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph shows serious confusion about how assembling into an ELF object file works.  `.text` is the default section at the top of a NASM source file; `section .text` has no effect if you haven't already switched to a different section.  `global _start` is relevant because it lets the linker see that symbol in the ELF metadata, which it's looking for by default.  IDK where you think your executable machine code would be if not inside the `.text` section, but that's the only section that NASM makes executable by default: https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my assembly subroutine being called even though I'm not calling it in \_start in my bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558656/why-is-my-assembly-subroutine-being-called-even-though-im-not-calling-it-in-st)  They seem to be working on the same project as you.

Comment: @NateEldredge  thanks, but I already figured it out and answered my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out when I was trying to do something else and I realised what I was doing wrong. The subroutine needs to come after the infinite jump, so for example:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov al, 'A'
call my_print_function
mov al, 'B'
call my_print_function

jmp $
my_print_function:
    mov ah, 0x0e
    int 0x10
    ret

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: Good self learner. Don't forget to mark your answer accepted after two days.

Comment: Yeah I will, and thanks for the compliment :)

Comment: You can use GDB to single-step your code (connected to QEMU as a gdb-remote).  That should make problems like this (and many others) obvious, e.g. when you see execution start at the top of the file, regardless of what's there.  (Should be obvious in hindsight: a 512-byte flat binary MBR has no metadata to indicate an entry point, only the 2-byte signature at the end.)  In code that changes segment registers or switches to protected mode, Bochs is good; unlike GDB, its built-in debugger is aware of segmentation.