# How does assembly code get compiled and run?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I saw assembly code that was supposed to create a boot sector in assembly. The code was:

```
jmp $
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

All is fine, but the first line is suppoused to create an infinite loop. I come from a higher-level abstraction programming, so in my head that means that the line will execute forever (because it will constantly keep jumping to the current address in memory), how does the rest of the code execute? Is it executed during the compilation? Also, usually x86 assembly code includes a 'start' section. Why does this code work?

Comment: The rest of the code doesn't *execute*; it gets *assembled* to put the `0xaa55` MBR signature as the last 2 bytes of the boot sector (the `.bin` file the assembler outputs).  It's not an interpreter.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Why is my assembly subroutine being called even though I'm not calling it in \_start in my bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70558656) , including comments under the question answering this question, that an assembler doesn't *run* the program as it turns source lines into binary bytes.  But the actual answer to that other question is pretty minimal, only addressing the `_start` entry-point question.  (Legacy BIOS bootloaders don't have metadata; execution starts at the first byte.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An assembler is just a tool, it takes bytes in one file and makes different bytes in another file. Just like a C compiler or a word processor (well the word processor takes input from the user turns it into bytes in a file and pixels on the screen).  Etc, etc.

Assembly languages are specific to the tool, not the target, x86 in particular is troublesome with the uncountable list of incompatible assembly languages (this is not an Intel vs at&t syntax thing, there are countless incompatible Intel x86 assemblers).

You do not compile assembly language (well some toolchains you use the compiler to do the assembling, sad, and some folks intentionally use the compiler so that they essentially get yet another assembly language from the same toolchain (using gcc instead of as gives you a different, incompatible, assembly language for the same target)) you assemble it.  The instructions are only a part of the language, the directives, how to create comments and labels, etc are also part of it.

Older assemblers you could basically end up with a final binary with directives like .org and such that let you pretty much use it as a linker.  Toolchains today though tend to be a compiler, assembler and linker.  You create objects (files) from the compiler and assembler and then link them together.  Think if a high level language like C where you will have multiple source files (if you choose) and one file may call functions in another, each C file will become its own object, and the linker not only links all the objects together defining their physical place in memory but also links the external references together so they can call each others functions.  Or access global variables.

(Some modern assemblers like NASM *do* still support making flat binaries, filling in symbol addresses itself instead of needing a linker.  This is how the NASM source in your question would normally be built into a 512-byte legacy BIOS MBR boot sector with no metadata, with `nasm -f bin foo.asm`.  But the GNU assembler, GAS, doesn't support doing that, and this answer only considers how things are done with the GNU toolchain.)

So I will try

```
jmp $
```

even though I'm quite certain that is not compatible with the assembler I am going to use (gnu assembler from binutils).

```
as so.s
so.s: Assembler messages:
so.s:1: Error: missing or invalid immediate expression `'
```

So instead

```
jmp .
```

and

```
as so.s -o so.o
objdump -d so.o

so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0x0
```

Much better I can build it and see the machine code that the assembler generated.  Part of the job of the assembler is to turn that human readable jmp into bytes/bits that the processor can actually execute (0xEB, 0xFE).

I am super rusty with my x86, I do not have much value in working with it at this level, but 0xFE is a -2 and it is a 2 byte instruction so this looks like an offset, so 0xEB is naturally the 8 bit x86 instruction, 0xFE the offset.  We can test this

```
here:
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
```

And I hate the x86 tools, hang on let us come back to this.

Linking, what is the start or _start thing all about.  That is not required at least for gnu toolchains, others perhaps, you have to write your code to the toolchain.  If you stick to high level languages and already built tools, even gnu, the gory details have been done for you.  High level languages need to be bootstrapped....in asm or some lower level language, chicken and egg problems if you try to bootstrap in the same language, some folks try, and eventually fail.

Note in gnu assembler, and understand gnu supports many "targets" (x86, arm, mips, etc) and not necessarily by design as each target is created possibly by a different person or team of authors, but more from borrowing existing target code to turn it into some new target code, things like jmp . the dot means this address it is short cut for here: jmp here, without having to type that much text.  you can do jmp .+2 in some of these gnu assembly languages...

If I do this

```
as so.s -o so.o
ld so.o -o so.elf
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <__bss_start-0x1000>:
  401000:   eb fe                   jmp    401000 <__bss_start-0x1000>
```

So we linked it as a final binary and the load/entry point is 0x401000.  But we did not specify any memory addresses to the linker, how did it decide this is where we wanted code?   Because the toolchain was built for my operating system (oh yeah, assume no two operating systems support the same binary file formats nor have the same rules for how the operating system loads said binary formatted files, as well as system calls being specific to each operating system and so on) and it is built with a C library and then some bootstrap code for that library plus target, and a linker script that is married to that bootstrap code for that library for that target.....there is a default.   And that default linker script, using the linker script language for the gnu linker, ld (assume no two toolchains use the same linker script language), contains

```
ENTRY(_start)
```

Which tells the linker to mark the entry point in the binary where the label _start was found.  Which does not have to be the first instructions in the program.  It can be almost anywhere, but per the rule of that operating systems loader.  Since I did not specify it chose the default linker script.

Now even if I:

```
ld -Ttext=0x1000 so.o -o so.elf
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000


objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <__bss_start-0x1000>:
    1000:   eb fe                   jmp    1000 <__bss_start-0x1000>
```

That is actually super painful and ugly, because it is taking someone else's linker script and hacking parts of it but leaving us with other parts:

```
jmp .
.data
.byte 0x55

ld -Ttext=0x1000 so.o -o so.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <.text>:
    1000:   eb fe                   jmp    1000 <__bss_start-0x1001>

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000002000 <__bss_start-0x1>:
    2000:   55                      push   %rbp
```

So if I make my own linker script

```
MEMORY
{
    one : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    two : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > one
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > two
}
```

and link with it

```
as so.s -o so.o
ld  -Tso.ld so.o -o so.elf
objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0x0
```

It stops complaining about _start.  Because mine does not have an ENTRY(_start)

But what if I:

```
ENTRY(banana)
MEMORY
{
    one : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    two : ORIGIN = 0x80000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > one
    .bss    : { *(.bss*)    } > two
}

ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol banana; defaulting to 0000000000000000
```

So it is easy to get the gnu binutils tools installed an you can see how easy it is to play with them...

So back to the other thing

```
here:
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
jmp here
```

disassembly of variable length instruction sets is quite painful, even gnu struggles, but sometimes you need to link and particularly when looking at jumps, branches, calls and such...

```
MEMORY
{
    one : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text   : { *(.text*)   } > one
}
```

objdump -d so.o

```
so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <here>:
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0 <here>
   2:   eb fc                   jmp    0 <here>
   4:   eb fa                   jmp    0 <here>
   6:   eb f8                   jmp    0 <here>
   8:   eb f6                   jmp    0 <here>
   a:   eb f4                   jmp    0 <here>

objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <here>:
    1000:   eb fe                   jmp    1000 <here>
    1002:   eb fc                   jmp    1000 <here>
    1004:   eb fa                   jmp    1000 <here>
    1006:   eb f8                   jmp    1000 <here>
    1008:   eb f6                   jmp    1000 <here>
    100a:   eb f4                   jmp    1000 <here>
```

It is the same machine code.  Assembly languages with overloaded mnemonics like x86 may have near and far jumps.

so.s

```
.globl one
one:
jmp two
```

x.s

```
.globl two
two:
jmp one
```

so.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    one : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    two : ORIGIN = 0x00002000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .one   : { so.o(.text)   } > one
    .two   : { x.o(.text)   } > two
}

as so.s -o so.o
as x.s -o x.o
ld -Tso.ld -o so.elf

objdump -d  so.o

so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <one>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <one+0x5>

objdump -d  x.o

x.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <two>:
   0:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   5 <two+0x5>

objdump -d so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .one:

0000000000001000 <one>:
    1000:   e9 fb 0f 00 00          jmpq   2000 <two>

Disassembly of section .two:

0000000000002000 <two>:
    2000:   e9 fb ef ff ff          jmpq   1000 <one>
```

at the object level (so.o, x.o) the assembler does not know where these labels are, so.s does not have a two label so the assembler assumes it is external and has to assume the distance away is a far jump and encodes as such (if it were to make an eb 00 for example and once linked the label is too far away now that code is in trouble and likely unusable, so the toolchain has designed in rules for how to resolve these things as we saw above with the jmp here ones.  Clearly that is a pc relative offset, it is not an absolute address.  Also with each instruction being two bytes, the offset as you go down the line is two further away.  If mixed in that code was a long jump to an external but the assembler encoded it as a short jump then the linker tries to resolve it if it inserts three more bytes and changes the opcode then the following jmp here instructions are now all hosed as they are complete machine code.

So anyway the assembler fills in zeros for the offset, and then the linker when it does its job replaces those zeros with the real offset.  Sometimes you will see the assembler encoded a jump to self (jmp ., here:jmp here) and then the linker patches that up.

```
b .
b two

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   eafffffe    b   0 <.text>
   4:   eafffffe    b   0 <two>
```

at the object level, and the b 0 is wrong for the second one that is really b 4...but since this is the object who cares.  It is a fraction of a program not a complete program.

Now, assembly language, C language, etc.  Compiled languages and assembled instructions are ultimately machine code.  The processor cannot execute the machine code nor C code directly it has to be converted into something it can execute, could you turn these languages into an interpreted language?  Sure, but generally not.

```
0000000000001000 <one>:
    1000:   e9 fb 0f 00 00          jmpq   2000 <two>

Disassembly of section .two:

0000000000002000 <two>:
    2000:   e9 fb ef ff ff          jmpq   1000 <one>
```

so at the end of the day, with x86 (64 bit etc etc etc) and any processor, the processors are very very very very dumb, they really only do what they are told.  The programmer is in complete control as to the processor crashing or not, very similar to a train if you do not connect the tracks up linearly and have the switches setup to take different sets of tracks, etc, the train will just crash.  As a programmer you must provide a sequential path of instructions that the processor will follow that is all it knows how to do, if you mess up the processor will perhaps stumble on bytes that look like code or maybe you get lucky and the train jumps through the air and just happens to land on some set of tracks somewhere, without crashing, but now the train is not where you wanted it so that is a harder to debug failure.

The e9 is read, that is known that the next four bytes, little endian are an offset.  Now 5 bytes have been consumed from where we started as programmers we think

```
one: jmp two
```

and think of "one" as the "address" of that instruction, but the (fake) program counter is five bytes in before it looks to do a pc relative jump, so the offset encoded in the instruction is five bytes off from the address one that we programmers are thinking of.  The tools do this for you if you let them.

So now the dumb processor takes the instruction and executes it and if I had actually linked this to work on an operating system this would be an infinite loop.  jmp to this address at that address jump to this address at that address jump to this address.

The j. is even simpler

```
   0:   eb fe                   jmp    0x0
```

Start executing code with the eb instruction those two bytes are the whole instruction, it is saying jump backwards two bytes.  Backward two bytes the (dumb) processor finds an eb and fe, that tells it to jump backward two bytes, it finds an eb fe, and .....forever or until interrupted.

Choose another assembler for x86 with different syntax and perhaps the $ means at this (label like) address here jmp here.

And since I do not mess with x86, I would not be surprised if that jmp is not actually executed and the thing you are looking at is a construct defined by the bios as a way to mark something related to booting. bios (x86) is a whole other very long book or set of books, how an x86 boots now and historically, etc.  If my guess is right then someone probably said, hey let's put a jump to self up front just in case someone tries to execute this. I could be very wrong on that, your questions were related to tools and execution and not about the boot sector itself.  Which while it has the name boot in it, it was designed as a thing the bios used to get that media started.  booting is often a series of steps from how the processor finds its first instruction on an often very limited single or set of media it can support, and then that code gets more of the processor or peripherals up to find other media and so on (bios on flash to boot sector on hard drive to file system to load a bootloader that then maybe loads kernel that has its own drivers for the peripherals and finds a file system and so on).  And you are looking at but one step in the ladder.

Oh yeah....and "how does it get run"  well barring the steps in the ladder above.

Normal (compiled/assembled/linked) programs are put into a binary format that is supported by the operating system (.exe, .coff, .elf, etc).  That file format has to conform to rules for that operating system.  Then when on a command line or point and click you try to run it the operating system has code that these days sets up a virtual environment/address space, that protects you from others and others from you, then loads the fractions of that file that are actually code and data into that virtual address space, then switches from superuser level for the processor into a user/application mode and jumps to the entry point defined by the binary.

Toolchains like gnu and llvm and others can be used to generate programs that do not conform to the specific host operating system.  The tools are somewhat generic.  You can make C programs without a main() and without support for the C library, it is somewhat trivial.  You could for example create some x86 code that if you knew how and where to put it on the flash that the processor uses to boot on your motherboard, it would run that code instead of the bios.  BUT you are now conforming to rules of a different environment, and many of the components of the binary file format that is the default output for that toolchain may not be used.  If you are creating the first instructions the processor boots, then there is no file system there is no operating system (sometimes no memory) there is nothing that can parse an exe or elf file, it is pure data and machine code.  You need some tool(s) that take the elf file for example and with some hardware or probes or magic box you put a chip in extract the bytes and program them into that chip.  Or some tool takes the elf file, makes another file format that the program the chip hardware knows how to use, per the rules of the program the chip hardware.

x86 is pretty much the worst first place you want to try this, "but I have one" is the worst excuse, you have four to 100 times as many arm processors as you have x86 processors.  But "I have one" is not a good reason. If you want to work at this level.  Start with a better and/or simpler instruction set/processor and a simulator/emulator.  You will not brick anything, you will not let smoke out of anything, and your odds of success are significantly higher because you have better visibility/debug into what is going on.  You can't see/debug that bios trying to read and use the boot sector on some media.  (unless you have an emulator for that or special tools and knowledge for that specific motherboard).

Comment: The code in the question is NASM syntax for a legacy 16-bit BIOS bootloader, an MBR, hence the 2-byte signature at offset 510.  It should get build with `nasm -fbin` to make a flat binary.  (Which gets loaded at a known linear address, but not with known segment-register settings, so if you need absolute addressing to work, e.g. for data, you need to use `org 0` or `org 0x7c00` *and* set `DS`.)  So a very different build and run process than a linked executable under an OS.

Comment: yep, certainly, and thus no need to define an entry point (start) because the build is for a target that is not os loaded, etc...and is a different assembly language, etc etc.

Comment: I bring that up because you wrote *Older assemblers you could basically end up with a final binary with directives like .org and such that let you pretty much use it as a linker.*  But NASM post-dates GAS.  It's an older *way of using* an assembler, one that GAS doesn't actually support.  And critically, is what's going on in the code this confused beginner is asking about, so I think it would be a good idea to explain that at some point.